# Execution time of program is "5E-006"?

Tags: c++, time, double

```
double SumOfSquare()()
{
    int i;
    double T3,total=0;

    for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
        clock_t start = clock();

        int n=100,sum=0;
        for(int i =1;i<=n;i++) {
            sum=sum+i*i;
        }


    clock_t end = clock();
    T3=double(end-start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    total=total+T3;
    }

    T3=total/200;

    return T3;
 }


 int main()
 {

    double T3=SumOfSquare();
    cout<<T3<<endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

This code is supposed to return a value for execution time of that code instead it returns some weird out put such as "5e-006" instead of the execution time.  Why?

Comment: `double SumOfSquare()()`  Really?

Comment: ahh i copied the code wrong it must be with out the second brackets

Comment: Please post a [short, self-contained, complete example (see sscce.org)](http://sscce.org/). Your example could be shortened to reveal the true nature of your problem, is missing at least one line of code, and has compilation errors in it.

Comment: Tangentially related to your question: if you run this with optimizations, no matter how large of values you chose for your two loops, you'll probably get the same answer.  The smart money is on the inner loop getting removed all together, and the whole thing basically becoming `for(i = 0; i < 200; i++) total += (clock()-clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`

Comment: @Rob the code runs fine, it just outputed something i didnt understand such as 5e-006 which is 0.0000005 ur wrong

Comment: @Rob: While better formatting, and a proper copying of the original source would have improved the question, I'm unconvinced it could be made any shorter.  He thought there was a problem with his function, so he provided it.  And he provided why he believed the function was not operating properly.  Had there *actually* been a problem, any less than this would have risked hiding his error.

Comment: The first for loop is used to get the average of excution times the second is used for the application iam getting the excution time for

Comment: @Anon: Yes, but my point is that, in reality, your compiler is *really* smart.  As written, it is entirely possible that it will notice that your inner loop calculates a constant value, and replace it with `sum=final_value;`  Then, it is almost certain to recognize that you set `sum`, then throw it away, so it will remove even that one line.  Suddenly, you're benchmarking a no-op.  Compiler's go out of their way to make benchmarking code difficult to get right, and they get better at it every day :-)

Answer (score 6):

`5e-006` is the same thing as `5 * 10^-6`, or `0.000005`. What makes you think that *isn't* the execution time?

(`5e-006` is a number written in [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).)

Answer (score 4):

T3 is a double and its value is 5 microseconds, so nothing is wrong.

Comment: ahh so instead of outputing 0.000005 it say this

Comment: @Anon - Floating point stream output will (pretty much) always print in exponential format. After all, the exponent could be really huge (or small), and printing all those zeroes would be kinda a waste of space.

Comment: @T.E.D. it's also more readable, assuming you understand the notation.

Comment: @T.E.D Floating point stream output will print in whatever format you tell it to.  The default using scientific format when fixed format would cause too many zeros to be output.  Which may or may not be the case, depending on the application.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at manipulators. They are used to format the output stream so you may get a more sensible looking result.

Comment: Write your own manipulator, so you can specify logically what you're outputting.

Answer (score 2):

5e-006 is simply the standard exponential notation for 5 * 10<sup>-6</sup>, i.e. 0.000005. This is the same as 6 µs.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, you're getting 5 microseconds as a result, which seems at least *reasonable* as the time.

I would, however, compute the time a bit differently. I'd accumulate the number of "ticks" for the loop, *then* convert the total to seconds:

```
static const int iterations = 200;
clock_t total=0;
double seconds;

for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
    clock_t start = clock();

    int n=100,sum=0;
    for(int i =1;i<=n;i++) {
        sum=sum+i*i;
    }
    total += clock() - start;
}

return total/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*iterations);
```

Instead of a floating point division and floating point addition every iteration, this does an integer addition each iteration, and a single floating point division at the very end. On low-end hardware, this is likely to be faster. More importantly, it's likely to be more accurate, almost regardless of hardware -- adding a long list of small numbers in floating point is one of the cases that frequently leads to a substantial loss of precision.

Comment: More importantly, I'd only do the call to `clock` before and after the outer loop.  I'd also make sure that `sum` was used somewhere; there's a very good chance that the compiler eliminates the inner loop completely, since it doesn't have any effect on the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: Hoisting the timing out of the loop would depend -- if you're trying to measure loop overhead, keeping in the loop could be important. Otherwise, I'd agree that timing the whole loop is probably better. I took for granted that is `sum` was used somewhere (at least it's not a local variable) but you're certainly right that it's better to state that explicitly.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin If the code in the loop is short, then you have to hoist the timing out of the loop to get any significant measurement; if the calls to `clock` are returning 0 or 1, you're not doing any significant measurement.  If you're worried about the effect of loop overhead, then comparing with an empty loop might improve things (but it is, admittedly, far from exact).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin And I think you missed the declaration for `sum`.  It's a local variable, but since it was declared on the same line as another local variable, it's very easy to miss.

Comment: @James Kanze: Oops, yes, so I did. As far as hoisting goes, yes, quite true. Basically, it depends on the granularity of results from `clock` compared to the time taken in the loop.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin The real problem is that the granularity of `clock` typically isn't sufficient for this sort of measurement.  (Especially under Windows, where `clock` is significantly  broken---and the results `"5e-006"`, rather than `"5e-06"`, as required by the standard, make me think that he is under Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that your code only takes 5 microseconds
to execute.  Probably because you never use `sum`, so the
compiler will eliminate any code used to modify its value (and
thus the inner loop).  More than anything else, your measurement
is probably determined by the granularity of `clock`.  You also
want to measure over as large a period as possible: I'd be
suspicious of the measurements if the two calls to `clock` are
less than about 5 minutes a part (but of course, I'll use a much
shorter interval when debugging the program:-)).  My solution
(and I'm not saying it's perfect) has generally been to put the
code to be measured in a virtual function, in a derived class,
with the function in the base class doing nothing, something
like:

```
class Base
{
    static int ourCount;
    static double ourTare;
    virtual void doRun();
public:
    double run();
    static void setCount( int count );
};

int Base::ourCount = 0;
double Base::ourTare = 0.0;

void Base::doRun() {}

double Base::run()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    for ( int count = ourCount; count > 0; -- count )
        doRun();
    clock_t end = clock();
    return (static_cast<double>(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC - ourTare;
}

void Base::setCount( int count )
{
    ourCount = count;
    ourTare = 0.0;
    //  The following has been sufficient in the past.  If the
    //  compiler inlines Base::run, however, it could be
    //  insufficent.  (In my own code, Base::run is in a
    //  separate translation unit.)`
    ourTare = Base().run();
}

class Derived
{
    int d;
    virtual void doRun();
public:
};

void Derived::doRun()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; ++ i ) {
        sum += i * i;
    }
    d = sum;
}
```

You then call `Base::setCount` with the count (for something
simple like this, anything less than around a million is
useless), create an instance of Derived, and call `run` on it to
obtain the total time in seconds.  You can divide it by the
count if you want the time per iteration.

(A more flippant answer would be that the program outputs
`"5e-006"` because the compiler is broken.  That's not a legal
output for any floating point value in C++.)